# Transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full: but Table created anyway?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that creates a temporary table and uses this table in later portions of the query. I ran the first part of the query which just creates the table to see the results. I obtained the following result:

Query Completed with errors:

```
(166166381 row(s) affected)

Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 3
The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases

Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 2
The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases
```

so it created the (massive) table, but gave me an error that indicated the transaction log for tempdb is full.

Did this error cause an issue with the table being shown (as in maybe not giving back all the rows) or am I ok to use this table? I looked around on tips to remove this error but when  I look at the tempdb properties it says I do not have permission so I am not sure on what steps to take for the error.

Here is the code. I can't seem to format it to fit in the code box for some reason

```
SELECT Cast(Datamart_Timestamp AS DATETIME) AS Datamart_Timestamp
   ,Contract_ID
   ,Admin_System
   ,Contract_Status_Code
   ,Cast(Contract_Status_Effective_Date AS DATETIME) AS Contract_Status_Effective_Date
INTO  ##Contract_Status
FROM   AV_TLA_Contract_Status AS CS
WHERE  (Datamart_Timestamp < '4/1/2011');

GO
--    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

INSERT INTO ##Contract_Status
SELECT CAST(CS.Datamart_Timestamp AS DATETIME) AS Datamart_Timestamp
   ,CS.Contract_ID
   ,CS.Admin_System
   ,CS.Contract_Status_Code
   ,CAST(CS.Contract_Status_Effective_Date AS DATETIME) AS Contract_Status_Effective_Date
FROM   AV_TLA_Contract_Status AS CS
   LEFT OUTER JOIN AT_AHEV_2011_04_Contract_Status AS A
    ON CS.Contract_ID = A.Contract_ID
WHERE  (CS.Contract_ID IS NOT NULL)
   AND (A.Contract_ID IS NULL)
   AND (CS.Datamart_Timestamp > '3/31/2011'); --Update so only most recent months are used.
```

Comment: You are OK to use this table because if not that would be an egregious corruption bug. Probably, there were further statements after the create table statement that failed.

Comment: great, thanks. I believe that there is one section that uses this temporary table (which selects items and creates in my own database) so hopefully nothing fails after!

Comment: Can you post your code?  While the table isn't "Corrupt", whatever statements happened after the 166 million row (presumably insert)  statement ran may not have completed.

Comment: I posted the code but the formatting isn't working for some reason not sure why it looks all messy

Comment: now that I am looking at the distinct dataes in the table I believe the second part of the query didn't go through. dates only go to 3/2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see any issue with using your created temp table. I believe, after creating the temporary table with `166166381 rows` the transaction log space got filled up and so the message is thrown and it's meant for future creation of temporary table.

Comment: Hmm, I see a downvote but no comment stating the reason. Strange!

Comment: I tried to upvote but need 15 reputation! that's weird that you received a downvote though

Comment: Aren't you assuming that the insert caused the problem?  You would have to see the code to be sure.  Also, a sev 17 error doesn't necessarily mean the table is OK.  It isn't corrupt, but if there are 5 prep steps and it failed on the second, how do we know things are ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can surely can use the table, but when you get a log full message, it means whatever activity that required logging failed to log, thus either got rolled back, or cancelled.  So, your table is there, but you could very well be missing a bunch of required changes and/or data.

As to how to deal with the error, you have two options:

1. Contact your dba and ask them to grow/expand the log size
2. Reconsider what you are doing - you just inserted 166 million rows into a temp table.  Is that necessary?  Can you insert a subset of data, that contains just the data you need?  If this is a shared database, you very well prevented other folks/applications from writing to tempdb.

Since you do not have permissions to modify tempdb, my guess is it is a shared db, and that a DBA would *not* grow the log for you, the dba would say do #2.

Comment: Hi Greg: We obtained the server just for our use (not shared). I believe I don't have permission to modify since the DB admin created it for us

Comment: ok, 166 million rows into a temp table is not good practice.  focus on #2,